# mlt failing after upgrade to fedora 36

Tags: mlt

Since upgrading my PC from Fedora 35 to Fedora 36, kdenlive has failed to render.  I traced the problem to mlt-melt.

```
$ mlt-melt export.mlt
+-----+ +-----+ +-----+ +-----+ +-----+ +-----+ +-----+ +-----+ +-----+
|1=-10| |2= -5| |3= -2| |4= -1| |5=  0| |6=  1| |7=  2| |8=  5| |9= 10|
+-----+ +-----+ +-----+ +-----+ +-----+ +-----+ +-----+ +-----+ +-----+
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|               H = back 1 minute,  L = forward 1 minute              |
|                 h = previous frame,  l = next frame                 |
|           g = start of clip, j = next clip, k = previous clip       |
|                0 = restart, q = quit, space = play                  |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
[consumer avformat] error with audio encode: -22 (frame 1)
[consumer avformat] error with audio encode: -22 (frame 11)
[consumer avformat] error with audio encode: -22 (frame 21)
Current Position:         20
```

```
$ mlt-melt --version
mlt-melt 7.4.0
...

$ dnf list mlt\*
...
Installed Packages
mlt.x86_64                                                                          7.4.0-3.fc36                                                                     @fedora        
mlt-freeworld.x86_64                                                                7.4.0-1.fc36                                                                     @rpmfusion-free
...
```

The exact same mlt file (which I generated on kdenlive 22.04.0 on F36) works fine on Fedora 35, which has mlt-melt 6.26.1 installed.  I didn't see any instructions that additional steps were needed to make mlt work on F36.  I get the same "audo encode -22" errors if I pull a working .mlt file from F35 to F36.

Any thoughts or suggestions?  I cannot roll back to F35.  I need a go-forward solution.  Thanks.

Comment: "error with audio encode: -22 (frame 1)" suggests a problem with your audio encode. Maybe a codec is working or an ffmpeg parameter has changed. Have you tried exporting to a completely different format or one with a different audio codec?

Comment: @Brian I tried a bunch of different audio encodings, none of them worked.  I thought it might have been ffmpeg, I even recompiled that, and that didn't make any difference.

Comment: I think it is an FFMpeg problem. The error is reporting an error code from FFMpeg: https://github.com/mltframework/mlt/blob/0e0e526124f4392275bdeb2510e8fb086d23da8f/src/modules/avformat/consumer_avformat.c#L2170

Comment: It's this error line: https://github.com/mltframework/mlt/blob/0e0e526124f4392275bdeb2510e8fb086d23da8f/src/modules/avformat/consumer_avformat.c#L1403

In any case, I have no problems transcoding the file with ffmpeg at all.  I really hate to have to build kdenlive to track down the ffmpeg command that it's using, but since I don't see it in the debug output, I guess I'm going to have to.

I know it doesn't matter, but if I take off the avformat consumer and let the render go to the screen, it works fine.

Comment: This problem can be due to using a newer version of FFmpeg than MLT is compatible with. Often when there is a new version of FFmpeg released, something needs change or update in MLT. I do not know what version of FFmpeg is being used, but look it up and compare its release date with that of your MLT version. It might take a few months after the FFmpeg release version for MLT to adapt.

Answer (score 0):

Error code -22 maps to the posix error EINVAL (Invalid argument). THis is the code FFMpeg is returning from the MLT call to avcodec_receive_packet().
https://github.com/mltframework/mlt/blob/0e0e526124f4392275bdeb2510e8fb086d23da8f/src/modules/avformat/consumer_avformat.c#L1376

If you trace the code in FFMpeg, there are any number of places that EINVAL is returned: https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/encode_8c_source.html#l00391

I think the most likely is that your FFMpeg does not have the codec you are trying to use - but you say it works when you use FFMpeg directly. Unless MLT is not finding the same FFMpeg that you are testing with. A good way to see if MLT is finding the codecs you want is to run:

```
melt -query audio_codecs
```

But that is just a guess. Maybe EINVAL error code is caused by a different problem.

As for other ideas... Well, you could use the AppImage or Flatpack provided by the developers themselves:
https://kdenlive.org/en/download/

Comment: The list is too long to post here, but the mlt file contains acodec="aac" in the consumer line, and the list starts with this:  

'''
$ out/bin/melt -query acodecs
---
audio_codecs:
  - comfortnoise
  - s302m
  - aac
  - ac3
  - ac3_fixed
'''

Comment: I'm getting mixed results with the AppImage version.  I've had a few renders work perfectly, and a few where the render is getting truncated.  I'm not finding any log files from the render to see why it's dying, but there's nothing happening in the video anywhere near the point of death.  That last point in the timeline where there's anything happening is about the 3 minute mark, but the render is dying at about the 33 minute mark...